# Will there be any televised first-round presidential debates in France during the "equal airtime" period that starts on 28 March 2022?

Tags: presidential-election, media, france

The rule in France in 2022 is that the media must treat verified candidates for the presidency "equitably" until 28 March, and from then on it must treat them "equally". So before 28 March airtime is allocated according to performance in opinion polls and in previous elections, and from that date onwards all 12 candidates are required to be given equal airtime.

This is complicated by some candidates deciding not to participate in certain planned debates.

Regarding the first round of the election, which is to say while there are still 12 candidates and their number hasn't yet been reduced to two, my question is whether any televised debates are foreseen in the "equality" period in which every candidate will be given a chance to participate.

Comment: Does this refer to political advertising, or to debates, or also to news coverage? For instance, if a candidate does something newsworthy but an outlet has already exceeded the time allotted to them by opinion polls, can they not cover it?

Comment: @Obie2.0 It depends on whether they did something newsworthy in their capacity as a candidate or not. E.g., the current president is a candidate, and he obviously does many newsworthy things, but not allowed to campaign while on the presidential duty - which is already a subject fo some controversies.

Comment: The _question_ is about televised debates only. The _rule_ is wider, and it does also apply to news coverage of campaigns. In governing the distribution of "exposure" it would cover direct campaign advertising too, but I am not sure whether they have that on the TV in France. (Note that opinion poll showings are relevant in the "equity" period but not in the "equality" period that this question is about.)